# Classpath problem with process-exec-maven-plugin (bazaarvoice) in Linux

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I'm using the process-exec-maven-plugin (bazaarvoice) to execute several process for my integration tests. I have some requirements of my company about how to use the artifacts. The main process (my maven module) is packaged in one jar (example: my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar) and the rest of the dependencies (jars) must be in a folder /lib inside the target. Due this it's needed to add the jar file and the /lib folder in the classpath.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.bazaarvoice.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>process-exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7</version>
    <executions>
      <!-- before I have other executions -->
      <execution>
        <id>demo-process</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>start</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <name>demo-process</name>
          <processLogFile>${project.build.directory}/logs/my-log.log</processLogFile>
          <arguments>
            <argument>java</argument>
            <argument>-cp</argument>
            <argument>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar${path.separator}lib/*</argument>
            <argument>com.example.Main</argument>
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

This works fine.

Now one of my dependencies inside the /lib folder is trying to access to a resource (properties file) of my current project. Hence I need to add into the classpath the folder where my resources are.

```
<argument>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar${path.separator}lib/*${path.separator}${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/</argument>
```

This change also works fine in my local environment with Windows.

But when I run the pipeline of my application in Jenkins (Linux environment) it's failing due to the main class is not found. The jar of my application (my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar) now is not being added to the classpath. So it's working fine in local but it is always failing in Jenkins.

I've tried different ways of configure the classpath in the pom using the plugin but is always failing.

I've tried with quotes

```
<argument>"${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar${path.separator}lib/*${path.separator}${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/"</argument>
```

Also using ${project.build.directory}

```
<argument>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar${path.separator}lib/*${path.separator}${${project.build.directory}/test-classes</argument>
```

Also changing the order

```
<argument>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}${path.separator}${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar${path.separator}lib/*</argument>
```

I've also tried to remove the * and use different versions of the plugin 0.8, 0.9.
I always have the same result, it works fine in my local environment in Windows but I can't get the java process work in the pipeline in Linux.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried running maven in debug mode `mvn -X ...` and checked the exact java command that's being executed? What happens when you execute that command outside of maven?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, I'm getting also errors on Jenkins and all working fine on my local mac OS, I am getting `java.lang.RuntimeException: Process was not healthy even after 90 seconds` on Jenkins